# How to display Google search results without the search bar in Android webview?

Tags: java, android, webview, textview

I have a webview in an activity where I display search results (let's say from google.com). 
However, I don't need the Google search field and the letters, "Web, Images, Videos,..." along with that grey line displayed in the webview. 
What are the ways to achieve this? (In other words, how to block the top part of the webview, if that's a solution. Are there other ways, like loading a different search results page without the search bar instead? Where to find it?)
This is my current layout file. ( I am open to removing the textview on top, if necessary). Thanks.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

<TextView
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:paddingBottom="10dp"
    android:text="@string/hello"
    android:textSize="20sp" />

<WebView
    android:id="@+id/webView1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Also, I have also seen professional apps display just News in a paper like container with news results. How do they achieve that?

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this by blocking HTML elements with javascript.
Just call the (e.g.) onLoadResource method of your WebViewClient and remove the elements you want to be removed with the following javascript. You need to inspect the element and get its TagName (e.g. div, section, a, header, body)

Example:

```
        webview.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
        public void onLoadResource(WebView view, String url) {
            super.onLoadResource(view, url);
            if (url.equals("www.google.com")) {
                view.loadUrl("javascript:(function() { " +
                        "document.getElementsByTagName('div')[26].style.display = 'none'; " +
                        "})()");
                }
            }
        });
```

The 26th div is the grey menu bar on the mobile device (You need to start counting with 0)
You need to navigate to google after initializing your WebViewClient. Also, if you want to remove more elements, get the chrome usb debugging dev tool and find out which elements have which tagname and then copy paste this  "document.getElements..." line again and change "div" to whatever you want to remove! The number in brackets tells you which Tag it is from top to bottom of the HTML code.

EDIT: 
If you inspect the code of the google page with your device it will look like this: http://prntscr.com/62jfnm if you hover over the line with the first

```
            webview.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
        public void onLoadResource(WebView view, String url) {
            super.onLoadResource(view, url);
            if (url.equals("www.google.com")) {
                view.loadUrl("javascript:(function() { " +
                        "document.getElementsByTagName('div')[26].style.display = 'none'; " +
                        "document.getElementsByTagName('form')[0].style.display = 'none'; " +
                        "})()");
                }
            }
        });
```

And voila: http://prntscr.com/62jj8t we have a nearly blank google page :)

Comment: I am unable to understand how to find the "div" ID from the webpage even when I look at the webpage debug page (from Chrome). The approach u stated above doesn't work for me, for random div ID numbers starting wt 0. For ex: what is the div id for the text bar that gets displayed by a Google search results page. How to know? Also, what's the syntax for adding multiple getElements... lines?

Comment: Hi, unfortunately, the code did NOT do anything. Here's my screenshot: http://prntscr.com/62nmty . I would like to know hw to identify the tags for 1. Google Logo. 2. Google search bar. 3. Google search button. 4) Google links that say a) Web b) News c) Images d) Maps e) More with a drop down icon and if it's possible to block them or at least make the user not see them by setting scroll from X to Y on the screen and not allowing the user to scroll beyond it? I can't find a method for that.

Comment: @Zac1 If you hover over the Html lines of code, you will see that the elements on the device's webpage get blue, then you know that this line is that one element. The tags you're searching for, are simply the first words after the <'s. To get the number, just type ctrl + f and search for this tag, and count (START WITH ZERO) from the top until you get to your tag, then take the number which is you tag.

Comment: Hi, I am completely lost. Can you please provide an example? Where is the line that shows the Google logo for example? What tag is it?